# Can I turn on the hotspot of an android device using python

Tags: python, android, hotspot

I know that android apps can be made in python. But I am not able to find anything that tells me how I can use python code to turn on/off the hotspot of an android device. Can anyone help  me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this repository, it's using java reflection to do that:

https://github.com/google/mobly-bundled-snippets/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/android/mobly/snippet/bundled/WifiManagerSnippet.java

The method you need:

`public void wifiEnableSoftAp(@Nullable JSONObject configuration)`

Comment: is there no python alternative?

Comment: after install the apk on android device, you can use python to control with https://github.com/google/mobly/blob/master/tools/snippet_shell.py